Conditional probability of drawing a red ball after drawing 49 reds from 1) an urn with 49 reds and one green, and 2) an urn with 50 reds.
I have an intuitive answer here, but I struggle setting up probability questions, so any pointers would be great.
There are 2 urns of 50 balls: one with 50 red balls and another with 49 red and one green. What is the probability of drawing a red conditional on drawing 49 reds from a randomly-sampled urn.
Here's how I set it up:
Call the urns $U_{1}$ and ${U_{2}}$, where $P(U_{1}) = P(U_{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$. Label drawing $n = 49$ consecutive red balls first event $A$, not drawing 49 red balls $\neg A$, and drawing a ball event $B = \{r, g\}$.
We are interested in $P(B = r \mid A)$, the probability of drawing a red ball after the event of drawing 49 consecutive reds from a randomly sampled urn. Using Baye's rule:
$$
P(B = r \mid A) = \frac{P(A \mid B = r) P(B = r)}{P(A)}
$$
The probability of drawing 49 reds given we've drawn a red ball is equal to the probability of drawing the all-red urn.
$$
P(A \mid B = r) = P(A \mid B = r, U_{1}) P(U_{1}) + P(A \mid B = r) P(U_{2}) = 1 \frac{1}{2} + 0 \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
The probability of a red ball overall requires summing over the possible ways of getting a red ball, i.e. a red ball from urn 1 or urn 2 and a red ball after sampling 49 red balls or not:
$$
\begin{align}
P(R) &= P(B = r, A, U_{1}) + P(B = r, \neg A, U_{1}) + P(B = r, A, U_{2}) + P(B = r, \neg A, U_{2})\\ &= \frac{1}{2} + 0 + 0 + \frac{49}{50} (1 - \frac{49!}{50!}) \frac{1}{2}\\
&= 0.9802\\
\end{align}
$$
Finally, the probability of 49 reds also requires us to marginalize over the possible ways of getting 49 reds:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A) & = P(A, B = r, U_1) + P(A, B = g, U_1) + P(A, B = r, U_2) + P(A, B = g, U_2)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + 0 + 0 + \frac{1}{50} \times \frac{1}{2}\\
&= 0.51
\end{align}
$$
Plugging these values into Bayes' rule gives me $0.961$.
Can anyone help with whether that is correct, and whether there are any better ways to set it up?

To be clear:  you select an urn uniformly at random and extract $49$ balls from it without replacement, note that all of those were red and then ask for the probability that the last ball in the urn is also red?

Note: You do not need $B$ to be a random variable, when you may make it an event, just like $A$.
So let $A$ be the event of drawing 49 red balls, $B$ be the event of the remaining ball being red, and $U_1, U_2$ the events for drawing from the indicated urn.
Of interest: when drawing from Urn 1, $A$ and $B$ are both certain (all balls must be red), while when drawing from Urn 2, $A$ and $B$ are complements, with $\mathsf P(A\mid U_2)=1/50$.
So:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B\mid A) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A, B)}{\mathsf P(A)}\\&= \dfrac{\mathsf P(A, B\mid U_1)\mathsf P(U_1)+\mathsf P(A, B\mid U_2)\mathsf P(U_2)}{\mathsf P(A\mid U_1)\mathsf P(U_1)+\mathsf P(A\mid U_2)\mathsf P(U_2)}\\&=\dfrac{1+0}{1+1/50}\\&= \dfrac{50}{51}\end{align}$$

Thank you. When I tried to compute $P(A \mid B)$ and $P(B)$, separately, I ended up $P(A \mid B) = 1/2$, but that wasn't correct. $P(A \mid B) = \sum_{k=1}^{2} P(A, U_{k} \mid B) P(U_k \mid B) = 1 + 0$. This means $P(B) = 0.5$. My confusion still is that, if $P(B) = \sum_{k=1}^{2} P(B, A, U_k) = 0.5$, then how do we write out $P(A)$ -- to me we need to write $P(A) = \sum_{k=1}^{2} \sum_{b=r, g} P(A, B_b, U_k)$ to get $1 + 1/50$. But why vary the outcomes of $B$ in this summation, but don't vary the possible outcomes of the first 49 balls ($A$ v $\neg A$) in $P(B)$? This is what led me astray.

@user_15 Well, firstly, $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\sum_{k=1}^2\mathsf P(A\mid U_k,B),\mathsf P(U_k\mid B)$ which equals $50/99$ . Secondly, you only need to partition over the urns. $\mathsf P(B) = \sum_{k=1}^2 \mathsf P(B, U_k)$ equalling $99/100$ and likewise $\mathsf P(A) = \sum_{k=1}^2\mathsf P(A, U_k)$ equalling $51/100$

Thanks, again. Is it correct to say, then, that an event is a discrete random variable when there are multiple options? In this example, $A$ and $B$ are events and do not need to made a d.r.v, but $U$ is a random variable because it can take on different outcomes -- $U_1$ and $U_2$? This whole time I've been saying there's three events and, when it comes to computing marginal probabilities, like $P(B)$, I keep trying to shoe-horn the other two events in there, which is leading to problems.

I guess another way of explaining my confusion is that I want to make the events $A$ and $B$ into booleans, resulting in $A$ and $\neg A$ and $B$ and $\neg B = \mathrm{green}$. I then used that principle to trying to write out the question, and along the way I screwed up. In this case, $P(B)$ is a sum not just over urns but over urns and $A$ and $\neg A$. Vice versa with $P(A)$.

@user_15 The point is only to do that which is useful. Partitioning over the urns is useful because having, or not, a green ball in the mix allows you to easily evaluate the conditional probabilities.$$\def\P{\mathsf P}\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c}\P(A\mid U_1)=1&\P(B\mid U_1)=1\\hline\P(A\mid U_2)=1/50&\P(B\mid U_2)=49/50\end{array}}$$Now you could go further, but how useful is it?$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c}\P(A\mid U_1, B)=1&\P(B\mid U_1,A)=1&\P(A\mid U_1,\neg B)=0&\P(B\mid U_1,\neg A)=0\\hline\P(A\mid U_2, B)=0&\P(B\mid U_2, A)=0&\P(A\mid U_2,\neg B)=1&\P(B\mid U_2,\neg A)=1\end{array}}$$

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A)&=\sum_{k=1}^2\sum_{\beta\in{B,\neg B}}\mathsf P(U_k)\mathsf P(\beta\mid U_k)\mathsf P(A\mid U_k,\beta)\&=\tfrac12\cdot 1\cdot 1+\tfrac12\cdot0\cdot0+\tfrac 12\cdot\tfrac{49}{50}\cdot0+\tfrac 12\cdot\tfrac 1{50}\cdot1\&=\tfrac{51}{100}\end{align}$

Thank you, Graham. You ask how useful that is -- for the question's purposes, not very, but for my purposes, it is very useful! Explicitly writing this out shows me where I was going wrong with three variables, and now I can get the calculations to match. For probability questions, I find having a rule to follow extremely useful. While I know intuition is used a lot in probability, it can be difficult to build it at first.

$$P(B=r|A)=P(U1|A)=\frac{P(U1 \cap A)}{P(A)}$$
Note that the numerator is $P(U1)$ and the denominator $$P(U1 \cap A)+P(U2 \cap A)=P(U1)+P(U2)P(A|U2)$$ now by symmetry this last term is equal to $1/50$ or the chance that the green ball appears in the last position of a random drawing order, since you have given that $P(U1)=P(U2)$ the terms cancel and we are left with
$$P(B=r|A)=\frac{1}{1+P(A|U2)}=\frac{50}{51}$$
Which should be slightly more than 0.98.

Thanks! Intuitively, this makes sense. But is there a way to arrive at this answer by not equating $P(B=r \mid A) = P(U_{1} \mid A)$? i.e. by keeping all events as I did in my OP. I'm trying to be better at setting up these problems, and it would be nice to see why I am not getting the same answer.

@user_15 Your error is the evaluation of $\mathsf P(B=r,\neg A, U_2)$ in the calculation for $\mathsf P(R)$.   $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B=r,\neg A,U_2) &=\mathsf P(B=r,\neg A\mid U_2),\mathsf P(U_2)\& = \tfrac {49}{50},\tfrac 12\&=\tfrac {49}{100}\end{align}$$  Since when drawing from the second urn, $B=r$ and $\neg A$ are the same event (that the green ball is among the first 49).

@user_15 by using sigma algebra's  countable additivity $P(B|A)=(P(B,U1,A)+P(B,U2,A))/P(A)$ the second therm is the intersection of all events where 49 red balls are present, the first 49 drawn are red and the last drawn is red. This provides a contradiction since no order of 49 red balls and 1 green ball contains 50 red balls. As for the first term $U1\subset B$ since every order of 50 red balls contains a red ball at the fiftieth position. An analogous argument is used for $P(U1\cap A)=P(U1)$, in fact just $A\cap B=U1$ suffices to solve this, but is not as general as the stepwise approach.

As a general tip if you don't want to use intuitive arguments always try to get a picture of what the events involved are, and then work towards events you have evaluations for using intersections and partitions.

Thanks @jucom. In the thread above, Graham Kemp sorted my marginalization issue out. Intuitively, I understand why the events are collapsed into $A \cap B = U1$, I was just making a mistake when marginalizing across the three events.

@user_15 ah i misunderstood your question, i thought you were looking for a way to rigorously prove this result rather than an error in your reasoning, glad you got it sorted out!

The way your question is framed, it is not clear that conditionality is involved.
On the other hand, using your symbols $U_1,U_2$ and $49R$ for $49$ consecutive reds if you are asking $P(U_1\mid 49R)$, it becomes
$\dfrac {P(U_1\cap49R)}{P(U_1\cap49R) + P(U_2\cap49R)}$
= $\dfrac{\frac12\cdot1}{\frac12\cdot1 + \frac12\cdot\frac{1}{50}} = 
\frac{50}{51}$
$P(U_2 \mid 49R)$ will obviously be the complement,  $1 - \frac{50}{51} =\frac{1}{51}$
Three hints that you may find useful are

see if you can reduce it to a familiar class of problems, like supplies from two factories with differing OK rates
use as few mathematical symbols as essential (can even use some English for greater clarity, but only where it can't be misinterpreted)
Use the "baby" form of Bayes' Rule until you gather more expertise

